# Как вывести окно камеры OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Диод камеры загорается, но окошка с изображением нет.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***main.py***

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Слишком простое было задание. Так что следующее идет бонусом

***main.py***

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Камера не обнаружена")
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    b = frame.copy()
    # Установка красного и зеленого канала на 0
    b[:, :, 1] = 0
    b[:, :, 2] = 0

    g = frame.copy()
    # Установка синего и красного канала на 0
    g[:, :, 0] = 0
    g[:, :, 2] = 0

    r = frame.copy()
    # Установка синего и зеленого канала на 0
    r[:, :, 0] = 0
    r[:, :, 1] = 0
    # RGB - Blue
    cv2.imshow('B-RGB', b)

    # RGB - Green
    cv2.imshow('G-RGB', g)

    # RGB - Red
    cv2.imshow('R-RGB', r)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```